# Migrating from .net core 3.0 to 3.1 causes missing System.Data.SqlClient assembly error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .net core project that references a .net framework library. The framework library uses `System.Data.SqlClient` to access a database. When the core project was running on dotnet core 3.0 everything was working fine. However, I just migrated to 3.1 and now I am getting the following exception:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried explicitly installing `System.Data.SqlClient` v. 4.6.0 via Nuget in the framework library, but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr: install the [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) metapackage into your Core/Standard project to fix this.

---

The version you are seeing in the error message is the **assembly version** that the .NET Framework project is expecting. This corresponds to the version that is shipped with the .NET Framework version that said project is compiled against.

Since .NET Core (and Standard) is far less tightly coupled than Framework, many namespaces that were previously part of the Framework have been broken out into their own NuGet packages. `System.Data.SqlClient` is one of these, so the answer is to install the appropriate version of that package into your .NET Core/Standard project... right?

Yes, but it's not the best answer.

Because SqlClient was developed independently of its NuGet package, the assembly version of that library *is not the same as the version of its package*, and in fact these versions *cannot be related simply by inspecting them*. The only way to figure out which version corresponds to which package is to manually inspect the NuGet package versions and compare them to the assembly version of the DLLs contained in those packages - I've done that hard work in the below table so you don't have to. Other namespaces and packages will likely have similar insanity going on.

**However!**

Microsoft has made the above pain *completely unnecessary* with the [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) metapackage. If you install it into your Core/Standard project, **the correct versions** of all packages that your Framework projects depend on will be pulled in. Not only that, if you change the version in your Framework projects, **the corresponding updated versions of the dependent packages will be pulled in the next time you do a build**!

This is far better than manually referencing the specific packages you need (such as `System.Data.SqlClient`), because if you install specific versions of those packages and changed your Framework version, things would again break at runtime. It's just unnecessary pain for pain's sake.

So, install [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility), and say goodbye to versioning hell!

### Reference list of System.Data.SqlClient versions

```
| NuGet package version | Assembly version | File version   |
|-----------------------|------------------|----------------|
|                 4.8.1 |          4.6.1.1 | 4.700.20.6702  |
|                 4.8.0 |          4.6.1.0 | 4.700.19.56404 |
|                 4.7.0 |          4.6.0.0 | 4.700.19.46214 |
|                 4.6.1 |          4.5.0.1 | 4.6.27618.01   |
|                 4.6.0 |          4.5.0.0 | 4.6.27110.04   |
|                 4.5.3 |          4.4.0.1 | 4.6.28516.10   |
|                 4.5.1 |          4.4.0.0 | 4.6.26606.05   |
|                 4.5.0 |          4.4.0.0 | 4.6.26515.06   |
|                 4.4.3 |          4.2.0.2 | 4.6.26212.01   |
|                 4.4.2 |          4.2.0.1 | 4.6.25921.02   |
|                 4.4.1 |          4.2.0.1 | 4.6.25706.01   |
|                 4.4.0 |          4.2.0.0 | 4.6.25519.03   |
|                 4.3.1 |          4.1.1.1 | 4.6.25220.01   |
|                 4.3.0 |          4.1.1.0 | 4.6.24705.01   |
|                 4.1.0 |          4.1.0.0 | 1.0.24212.01   |
```

Answer (score 4):

You're probably no longer stuck on this, but for me upgrading `System.Data.SqlClient` from 4.7 to 4.8.1 resolved the issue.

I had previously tried uninstalling and reinstalling 4.7 without any luck.