# Possible to use the "System.Data.SqlClient" package in a .net Standard 2.0 library without having to also add the package to consuming assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

Consider a class library called "SqlLib" using the "System.Data.SqlClient" package as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The library contains a very simple test class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlLib
{
    public sealed class Test
    {
        public object AccessSql()
        {
            var p = new SqlParameter("My param", "My value");
            return p.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I reference this from a .net Core 3.1 console application:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SqlLib">
      <HintPath>..\SqlLib\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SqlLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

With the code:

```
using System;
using SqlLib;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var t = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine(t.AccessSql());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so simple. Now when I run the console application I get:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.2,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot
> find the file specified. File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient,
> Version=4.6.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> at SqlLib.Test.AccessSql()

I have to fix this by explicitly adding the package to the console application. As far as I can see I shouldn't have to do this. (The same problem occurs when consuming the class library from something targeting "net48" too.)

What am I doing wrong?

---

I did discover this: https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/

So it looks like it should work for PACKAGE dependencies, but in this example the class library has a package dependency, but the executable is depending on an assembly, not a package.

Comment: Why do you think you do not needed to add explicitly?  Core is a compact version of Net library and is meant for mobile applications with less memory that a standard machine.  So the libraries in core are the minimum that Microsoft thinks most people are using.

Comment: @jdweng Because I would expect the leaf assembly to automatically include the set of packages referenced by all the non-leaf assemblies. For example, if I have dependencies like A -> B -> C, and I add a package to C I would expect it include that package automatically when compiling A. Having to do this manually is surely a maintenance issue...  (In .Net Framework, if you add a reference to an assembly that assembly is automatically included in any assemblies that indirectly reference it.)

Comment: I have a feeling this might be relevant, I will investigate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723396/native-dependencies-not-copied-when-indirectly-referenced-as-a-nuget-dependency#:~:text=When%20the%20NuGet%20package%20with%20native%20dependencies%20is,then%20the%20native%20dependencies%20are%20copied%20over%20properly.

Comment: Instead of depending on the specific assembly, depend on the *project* instead. Basically if you can use project or package dependencies (rather than assembly dependencies) life works out a lot better.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to avoid having to make sweeping changes. We're porting to .Net Core nearly a million lines of code spread over hundreds of projects so I'd like to localise the changes to minimise disruption - updating all the projects to use project references would not be ideal. (Using package dependencies would probably be better, but changing hundreds of projects to output nuget packages and would be even slower). Our ".proj" file is automatically generated by a tool so perhaps something can be done there... I'd like this to work as easily as .Net Framework does though ;)

Comment: @jdweng: I think you're thinking of the Compact Framework, rather than .NET Core.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Fundamentally, it's a different build system, with somewhat different behavior. Even though it'll be a bigger initial change, I would embrace it rather than trying to make .NET Core behave as if it were .NET Framework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62151787/70345

Comment: @JonSkeet : No.  Core is designed to run on Windows 10 and on Mobile Devices.

Comment: @jdweng: No, .NET Core was designed to be portable across OSes from the start - it was far more about being able to run webservers on Linux than being able to run on mobile. (The whole project was started by an off-shoot of the ASP.NET team.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : But it still important on servers that are serving large number of users to keep memory usage small.

Comment: @jdweng: Sure, but that's not primarily driven by the size of libraries (it's working-set space), and it's still *completely* different from saying it's "meant for mobile applications". Over time, .NET Core (now just .NET) has evolved so that it *is* suitable for mobile applications, but that's not the history of it... and the libraries in .NET Core (now .NET 5) are pretty complete. Not that it's relevant to the question anyway, which is really about transitive dependencies, rather than the size of the "core" framework. (The same question could equally apply to any other transitive dependency)

Comment: Well it turns out that you can't reference a project that's not part of the solution, you get an error along the lines of `Unable to find project information for 'project.csproj'. If you are using Visual Studio, this may be because the project is unloaded or not part of the current solution` so unfortunately that's out. (We have more than 600 projects in our build, so it's not practical to put everything in one solution!)

Comment: The reference doesn't use the csproj file.  You reference a dll and the pdb file which contains the debug info.

Comment: @JonSkeet : You have to look at all the requirement.  The Core requirements were to create an library that would run on both windows and linux as well as on servers and mobile devices.  All the ASP teams was to copy the ideas of K & R at Bell Labs whose goals were to develop one operating system that could be used by Operators, Switching Equipment, and Bill System.

Comment: @jdweng: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I don't think it's productive to discuss this any further in comments.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I believe you *can* reference a project that's not in the solution, just not in Visual Studio. One option you might want to consider is a giant solution where most of the projects are unloaded.